# convert date/time format to a date only in a query

Tags: php, laravel

The following is the required date format :

```
$sel_date = date('Y-m-d');
```

But the created_at field has the full date/time format :

```
2019-10-15 16:14:18
```

I need to add to the query only the date by omitting the time, as below :

```
->where('created_at', $sel_date )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
->whereDate('created_at', $sel_date)
```

Some documentation about additional `where` queries [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses).

Comment: Missing argument 3 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::whereDate()

Comment: Well that's weird, laravel documentation says it should be fine. Try using 
->whereDate('created_at', '=', $sel_date)

Answer (score 0):

use the following

```
CAST("2017-08-29" AS DATE)
```

ref [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `date()` function of mysql.

```
->where('date(created_at)', $sel_date )
```

Comment: Unknown column 'date(created_at)' in 'where clause'